# Aliasing a domain on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, localhost, serveralias

I am developing a website on my own development servers. The client is loading some fonts that are white-listed on just their domain, the problem is that during development I cannot see them on my dev server. Someone said I can somehow alias the domain via Apache and use a hosts file to point at the domain so the request for the fonts gets through as though from the appropriate domain since they've white-listed *.theirdomian.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have successfully aliased the client's domain to my own server. Here is how:

In your `vhosts.conf` file create an alias to a fake subdomain to your clients site. For example if your client is `www.myclient.com` create `local.myclient.com` or something:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

     ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
     ServerName dev.mydomain.com
     ServerAlias local.myclient.com
     DocumentRoot /var/path/to/your/files/dev.mydomain.com/html/

     <Directory />
         Options FollowSymLinks
     </Directory>
     <Directory /var/path/to/your/files/dev.mydomain.com/html>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
     </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to issue the reconfigure command on your Apache server and restart.

In your `hosts` file on your local machine, point the ip of your server (dev.mydomain.com) to the fake domain:

```
xxx.xx.xx.xxx     local.myclient.com
```

Go to `local.myclient.com` in your web browser and you should see the contents of `dev.mydomain.com`. The calls will seem to come from the client domain, and fonts will be white listed (so long as they've white-listed `*.myclient.com` and not `www.myclient.com`)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a test if you can curl or wget the font files directly.  If you can, you'll need some server configuration to make them accessible; some browsers make it very difficult to do cross domain fonts.  If you can't, you'll need to acquire those fonts directly from your client.